# iOS Background Notifications not always delivering

Tags: ios, push-notification, background, firebase-cloud-messaging, uikit

in my UIKit app I am using **push notifications** which are send to the device from Firebase with **content-available** set to true. I am updating the users location on a server with that. The user shouldn't see the application and the notification also needs to **deliver in the background**.

**My Problem**:
The notifications are generally working. But sometimes the notifications doesn't get delivered when the app is too long in the background and closed by the user. But on other devices there is no problem with delivery at all. It just seems that the delivery is not stable and therefore hard to rely on.

Do you have any ideas how to solve that or strategies?
For referance, this is the same topic, but it seems there was never really an answer found: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/8564

Comment: Silent notifications are not guaranteed.  They are rate limited and they will not relaunch an app that has been terminated

Comment: I know, but this is a core feature of my app. Do you have any workarounds to get the best possible performance?

Comment: Or do you have any strategies on how to prevent the app to get terminated?

Comment: Don't poll the device via push notifications. Use a suitable "always" location mode, such as significant location change